# jenkins fails builds using maven 3

Tags: hudson, maven-3, jenkins

Jenkins build 1.411.

Building the multimodule project with maven 2 works, but using maven 3 gives this not too descriptive error:

```
message : Internal error: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
cause : null
Stack trace : 
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.handleBuildError(BuilderCommon.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:128)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:75)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:270)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy2.setResult(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuildProxy$Filter.setResult(MavenBuildProxy.java:212)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuildProxy$Filter.setResult(MavenBuildProxy.java:212)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.reccordProjectSucceeded(Maven3Builder.java:428)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.projectSucceeded(Maven3Builder.java:421)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:74)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:91)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remote call on channel failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:652)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:158)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
    at hudson.model.Run.setResult(Run.java:341)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuild$ProxyImpl.setResult(MavenBuild.java:427)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuild$ProxyImpl2.setResult(MavenBuild.java:469)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at hudson.model.Executor$1.call(Executor.java:429)
    at hudson.util.InterceptingProxy$1.invoke(InterceptingProxy.java:23)
    at $Proxy62.setResult(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:274)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:255)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:215)
    ... 9 more
channel stopped
```

Comment: Does it work, if you run the build locally on your computer?

Comment: Yes, it works building the project in the workspace dir (jenkins) using maven 3

Comment: Do you have a distributed Jenkins environment, where the problem could lie on a misconfigured slave?

Comment: no - no slaves are configured

Comment: So far i have no more ideas. Can you try it with the latest Jenkins version and post your poms?

Comment: I think, the plugins section of your poms should be enough at first, because that's the most likely part, where i would expect problems between Maven 2 and 3, namely with plugin versions, that don't work with Maven 3

Comment: still same error with latest jenkins, I'll check into plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to latest Jenkins. There have been numerous fixes since the version you list. I would not recommend Hudson v2.x and beyond, although Maven integration has been improved, the rest of the system has suffered tremendously.

Comment: finally had time to check into it, removing sources and javadoc plugins solved it

Answer (score 0):

You should try the Maven 3 integration in Hudson 2.1 beta ... that should work like a charm. Otherwise configure the build as a freestyle project with a Maven build step.